# Rename [once-upon-time-in-america]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Can the tag [once-upon-time-in-america](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/once-upon-time-in-america) be renamed to [once-upon-a-time-in-america](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/once-upon-a-time-in-america), which is its [real name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Once_Upon_a_Time_in_America)? The existing name is clearly an artifact of the old 25 character max tag length.